# MySQL error message "select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting

Tags: mysql

I am new to Mysql. I wrote a nested SELECT to find the employee id, first name, last name, job title and email of all employees working in Asia in the workbench.
I am getting an error message:

> select is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : '(', WITH"

The select that is underlined is the very first one.

```
SELECT employee_id,frist_name,last_name,job_title,email
 FROM  EMPLOYEE
WHERE department_name 
IN(SELECT department_name
 FROM DEPARTMENT
WHERE street_address, postal_code, city, country_name
IN(SELECT street_address, postal_code, city, country_name
 FROM LOCATION
WHERE country_name
IN(SELECT country_name
 FROM COUNTRY
WHERE region_name
IN(SELECT region_name
 FROM REGION 
WHERE region_name='Asia'))));
```

below is my database

```
CREATE TABLE REGION(
region_name    VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT REGION_PK PRIMARY KEY(region_name) );

CREATE TABLE COUNTRY(
country_name    VARCHAR(40)     NOT NULL,
region_name     VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT COUNTRY_PK PRIMARY KEY(country_name),
 CONSTRAINT COUNTRY_FK FOREIGN KEY(region_name)
        REFERENCES REGION(region_name) );


CREATE TABLE LOCATION(
street_address VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
postal_code    VARCHAR(12)  NOT NULL,
city           VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
state_province VARCHAR(25)      NULL,
country_name   VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT LOCATION_PK PRIMARY KEY(street_address, postal_code, city, country_name),
 CONSTRAINT LOCATION_CK UNIQUE(street_address, city, state_province, country_name),
 CONSTRAINT LOCATION_FK FOREIGN KEY(country_name)
        REFERENCES COUNTRY(country_name) );


CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT(
department_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
street_address VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
postal_code    VARCHAR(12)  NOT NULL,
city           VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
country_name   VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
manager_id     DECIMAL(6)       NULL,
 CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY(department_name),
 CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(street_address, postal_code, city, country_name)
        REFERENCES LOCATION(street_address, postal_code, city, country_name) );


CREATE TABLE JOB(
job_title      VARCHAR(35)  NOT NULL,
min_salary     DECIMAL(6)       NULL,
max_salary     DECIMAL(6)       NULL,
 CONSTRAINT JOB_PK PRIMARY KEY(job_title) );


CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE(
employee_id    DECIMAL(6)   NOT NULL,
first_name     VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
last_name      VARCHAR(25)  NOT NULL,
email          VARCHAR(25)      NULL,
phone_number   VARCHAR(20)      NULL,
hire_date      DATE     NOT NULL,
job_title      VARCHAR(35)  NOT NULL,
salary         DECIMAL(8,2)     NULL,
commission_pct DECIMAL(2,2)     NULL,
supervisor_id     DECIMAL(6)        NULL,
department_name VARCHAR(30)     NULL,
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PK PRIMARY KEY(employee_id),
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_CK1 UNIQUE(email),
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_CK2 UNIQUE(phone_number),
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(department_name)
        REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(department_name),
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(supervisor_id)
        REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(employee_id),
 CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(job_title)
        REFERENCES JOB(job_title),
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_CH1 CHECK (salary > 0) );

ALTER TABLE DEPARTMENT
ADD ( CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(manager_id)
              REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(employee_id) );


CREATE TABLE JOBHISTORY(
employee_id   DECIMAL(6)    NOT NULL,
start_date    DATE      NOT NULL,
end_date      DATE          NULL,
job_title     VARCHAR(35)   NOT NULL,
department_name VARCHAR(30)     NULL,
 CONSTRAINT JOBHISTORY_PK PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, start_date),
 CONSTRAINT JOBHISTORY_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(job_title)
        REFERENCES JOB(job_title),
 CONSTRAINT JOBHISTORY_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(employee_id)
        REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(employee_id),
 CONSTRAINT JOBHISTORY_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(department_name)
        REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(department_name),
 CONSTRAINT JOBHISTORY_CH CHECK (end_date > start_date) );
```

Comment: Could you show use your database structure ?

Comment: i edited and add database structure  to the question, thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The error point is:

```
...
WHERE street_address, postal_code, city, country_name
IN (SELECT ...
```

The columns group must be wrapped with parenthesis:

```
...
WHERE (street_address, postal_code, city, country_name)
IN (SELECT ...
```

2. Also a typo is present (`frist_name` instead of `first_name`) in 1st row of a query.

---

While correcting above problems the query becomes legal: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b6ebe5c642c3dfcc624d510eb4b6b726).

---

3. Shown error message is **NOT** produced by MySQL.